# Unable to install Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, yum, rhel6

I installed VM in Oracle VM VirtualBox manager and mounted /dev/sr0 and configured system.repo under /etc/yum.repos.d as below.

```
 [SYSTEM]
    name=rhel6
    baseurl=file:///mnt
    gpgcheck=0
    enabled=1
```

and downloaded epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm from one of Fedora site to install Ansible.

But yum command is not working and getting error as "Error: Cannot retrieve  metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again"

I did a few changes in epel repo file like replaced https as http for mirr  orlist option but after that when I run any yum command it gives below message.

> Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 2448.
>   Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to
>   exit...

and when I kill the yum id and run again any yum command it gives an output as yum command killed.

Comment: We all have a local `yum` or `dnf` repo, a virtual box should have the same behavior as a real machine, the `baseurl` then should be a real one, I am eager to know the answer as well

Comment: I dint get you could you explain what can i do to fix it.

Comment: what about installing ansible with `pip install ansible` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, from your virtualBox, do `yum search epel`, and then `yum install epel-release`.

If epel is not available from `yum`, in your case, do:

rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm

The above one of the steps will make the EPEL repo installed properly.

The repo's name will be epel.repo, like this:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
```

You will probably need to restart the yum service by:

```
service yum restart
```

find the package first by:

```
yum search ansible
```

and then `yum install ansible`

Your `baseurl` is `/mnt`, I doubt there is anything in it, it should be either a local repo or some real site for `yum` search `rpm` package.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but when i ran the same yum install ansible in my office network it ran but at the end throwed below error.--> Finished        Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: ansible-2.2.1.0-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python-six
Error: Package: ansible-2.2.1.0-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: PyYAML
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: @sudhakar, choose a different repo other than `epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm` then

Answer (score 0):

To find out what's locking yum, try running the following command

## ps aux | grep yum

This shall give you a list of running processes, something in the following format

root       **2748** 10.7 18.9 1101752 189236 ?      SN   10:31   0:47 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/yum/yumBackend.py get-u             pdates none

root       **3713**  0.0  0.0 112660   968 pts/1    R+   10:39   0:00 grep --color=auto yum

Here, "2748 " is my PID

Now, run the following command to kill this particular process

## kill

Acc, to the above given example, my command should be

## kill 2748

After running this command, again run 
**# ps aux | grep yum** to check whether the process has been killed or not, if not, again run this command, since some processes are really stubborn. Once the process is killed you can continue with the yum command.

Hope this helps :)